# Moving a monero wallet+ node from a disk to another one

Tags: cryptocurrency

I dont know where to put this question, and the most appropriate would be here i guess, i found no criptocurrency stack, if its not here i would apreciate a link to post this

I've downloaded a monero node on my laptop which roughtly took 105GB and a full night even though it said it was only 5 hours of work

And since im running out of space i thought of moving the node elsewhere, i know that you can use a remote one but i would like to help out

But then i remembered "wait i could kill 2 birds with one stone", the other bird being the future expenses of keeping a server open most of the time, so i was thinking of mining in a pool to cover the electricity expenses of the server(which is just an old desktop with barely nothing in it)

***Now for the relevant part***, is it possible to just copy the files related to the monero wallet+ node to the server so that i don't have to spend 5+ hours putting it in the server?
From what I've gathered, the ledger should be equal so copying shouldnt cause problem, the problem would be the wallet im not shure if it might have some input/hash related to the computer its running?
Both Computers run Arch Linux

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cryptocurrency software questions are off-topic here.

Comment: This question is closed because practicalities, economics, and sociology of cryptocurrencies are straight off-topic. See [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [_Do we want bitcoin/cryptocurrency related questions?_](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/555). Also, Ponzi schemes are illegal in some jurisdictions. I don't see an adequate SE site for migration of the question. On the redeeming side, it's well-written.